# Avoid UserControl to catch mouse wheel scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, user-controls, mouseevent

We have a `UserControl` showing all possible values of an enum represented as `RadioButton` in a `ListBox` to choose one of them. When this control is inside a `ScrollViewer` with other controls like textboxes or whatever and you try to scroll by mouse wheel it won't scroll the form's `ScrollViewer` when the mouse cursor is over the EnumBox.

This is how it looks like in an UI:

[image: EnumBox in UI]

For demonstration the `RadioButton`s have yellow background, the `WrapPanel`'s background is green. When the mouse cursor is within the colored area (say within the `WrapPanel`) scrolling by mouse wheel has no effect.

The Template for the EnumBox looks like this:

```
  <UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type clientsWpf:EnumBox}">
      <StackPanel>
        <GroupBox Header="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type clientsWpf:EnumBox}}}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type clientsWpf:EnumBox}}}">
          <Border x:Name="InvalidBorder"  BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0" >
            <ListBox x:Name="PART_ListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" SelectedValuePath="." SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type clientsWpf:EnumBox}}}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
              <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Green"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
              </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
              <ListBox.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
                  <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                      <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border Background="Transparent" Background="Yellow">
                          <RadioButton Margin="3" Focusable="False" Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content,Converter={StaticResource enumValueDescriptionConverter}}" 
                                     IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},Path=IsSelected}" />
                        </Border>
                      </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                  </Setter>
                </Style>
              </ListBox.Resources>
            </ListBox>
          </Border>
        </GroupBox>
      </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </UserControl.Template>
```

I tried to set `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` and `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"` on the `ListBox`, `WrapPanel`, `RadioButton` and its `Border` with no effect.

I tried to catch the `ScrollBar.Scroll="WrapPanel_Scroll"` event on all four controls but none of them got hit.

I tried to set `SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="None"` on the `RadioButton` with no effect.

Does anyone have a clue on what prevents the scrolling in the UI?

To make it clear: It is not about scrolling within the EnumBox but to scroll the whole form.

Comment: try one thing, click on the control and then do scroll using mouse wheel, if it works then you need to set focus to the control when ever it is activated on the form

Comment: @Habib.OUS: This doesn't help. I hope it is clear, that I want to scroll up and down the whole form/page/grid/window or whatever the EnumBox is part of in the UI. I do not want to scroll within the EnumBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `ListBox` has its own `ScrollViewer`.  Copy the template for the `ListBox` and remove the embedded `ScrollViewer`.

Here's a complete example with the embedded `ScrollViewer` commented out:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBorder" Color="#828790"/>
        <Style x:Key="ListBoxStyleNoScrollViewer" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ListBorder}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <!--<ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">-->
                                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            <!--</ScrollViewer>-->
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyleNoScrollViewer}" >
                <ListBox.Items>
                    <ListBoxItem>One</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem>Two</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem>Three</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem>Four</ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox.Items>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

If the list box has `Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyleNoScrollViewer}"` then the scroll wheel works when over the list box.  If not then the sample exhibits the problem you mention.

Comment: Ah, Thanks Phil, I should have known :) It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you set the background to transparent on your `ListBox`, `Border` etc.. It prevents it from receiving focus as well as mouse events. Give your `ListBox` a color but flip an A part of RGBA on it.. Try this one for example:  #000A0A09 (its black with A = 0%, which makes it look transparent)

Comment: Thanks Denis, but changing the color does not help in this case.